# Ubuntu 14.10 -TPM error(7) occured

Tags: boot, caching

Ubuntu 14.10 no caching page found on all hard drives 2 sata and two IDE also same if I mount avusb drive.

After upgraded from 14.04.1 and also from a clean install of 14.10

During boot I get error on all hard drives no caching page found. I never had this problem on Ubuntu 14.04.1 and below yet on 14.10 it exists and cripples the performance of the system?

The exact error during boot is:

```
A TPM error(7) occured Trying to read a pcr value

ata4 srst failed (errorno=-16)

sddd no caching mode page found
sddd assuming disk write through
sdde no caching mode page found
sdde assuming disk write through
```

Any help please?